# Reformat localized date string to another locale

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, date-formatting, nslocale

I have a `String` that is `"Jueves 14 Junio 1990"`: it is a date formatted in the `es_MX` locale, I want to convert that into a new string with `en_US` as the locale.

This is my code:

```
let myString:String = "Jueves 14 Junio 1990"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE dd MMMM yyyy"
let finalDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(myString)!
let finalString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

I was waiting that `finalString` resulted as `Thursday 14 June 1990`.

The problem here is that `finalDate` is `nil`.

Is my code wrong? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use es_MX locale first to convert the string to NSDate:

```
let string = "Jueves 10 Junio 1990"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE dd MMMM yyyy"
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "es_MX")
if let date = formatter.dateFromString(string) {
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
    let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
}
```

Comment: though this right now prints Sunday, so I guess June 10, 1990 is a Sunday

Comment: You're totally right, thanks for the solution! Just realice that I mistaken the 10, it was actually a 14.